# Stoppable and reexecutable thread in java concurrency package?

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there a concurrency structure (like a thread) in java which can execute runnables and be stopped and reexecuted, or do I have to implement it on my own?

Comment: Are you looking for `java.lang.Thread`?

Comment: Nope, Thread can not be safely stopped.

Comment: Thread can be safely stopped. You cannot externally force a Runnable to stop safely, it has to be written correctly to be safely stopped.

Comment: `do I have to implement it on my own` if you manage this for any kind of Runnable in a simple way, you deserve a prize !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), example [here](http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/thread-pool-executor-example-j2ee).

If, as Peter Lawrey suggested, you are after a reliable Runnable's lifecycle manager then Java is not the right tool. If a thread (or a task in an executor) hangs the best recovery behavior is to have a watchdog thread that will commit process suicide with "restart me" exit code and have an external launcher (shell script, etc.) to restart the process which dies with "restart me" exit code.

Comment: I get the impression the OP want to be able to safely kill a Runnable which is not behaving correctly.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - thanks for the comment, I have updated the answer with my opinion on the subj.